# My app in Android Studio using Kotlin restarts upon rotation (using seperate landscape and portait XML files)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, rotation, manifest

So I'm making an application in Android Studio using Kotlin and have 2 xml files, one for portait mode and the other for landscape mode. Switching between them was fine but I noticed that the app "restarts" upon rotating, more specifically the data is reset. So if I interacted with the app and got new numbers, the numbers are reset upon rotating. Here's my AndroidManifest.xml file if it'll be of any help

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Weather">
    <activity

        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true">
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I saw some solutions like how in the AndroidManifest.xml file I can have something along the lines of android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" but that only let's me keep my data after rotating but doesn't use the landscape xml file I have.

So what I'm trying to do is be able to switch from landscape to portrait mode and vice versa without resetting my data. So far, I either use only one of the XML files and not reset my data or use both XML files accordingly but my data resets. How do I make it so that I can use either XML file when rotating my phone without resetting the data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated my question. I would like to be able to switch from portrait to landscape mode and vice versa using my 2 XML files containing these different modes without having my data reset to default. I see now after reading your comment that my question was not clear

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will keep the current layout as it is, including the one you had in portrait mode.

Try to set ,layout again when **configuration change**

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
}
```

Comment: But is there another approach regarding the layout? I'm very new to this but is there a way to simply display one layout or the other while transferring all the data and not have it reset?

Comment: Remove "screenSize" from  android:configChanges and if you want to persist data on screen rotation please use MVVM structure and if you could additional details about what you want to achieve I can tell you the exact solution.